# Page's album tags doesn't appear on timeline

Tags: photo

When I upload an album of photos on my Page, and then people tag themselves, the pictures won't appear on their timelines or photos tab in their profile. Why is that?

Comment: You might want to add extra tags to this question - I assume it's about Facebook, from the description. That said, you might be better off addressing this to Facebook support?

Comment: Well I was referred to here by Facebook.